# RegEx: Find all digits after certain string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get all the digits from following string after the word `classes` (*or its variations*)

```
Accepted for all the goods and services in classes 16 and 41.
```

expected output:

```
16
41
```

I have multiple strings which follows this pattern and some others such as:

```
classes 5 et 30 # expected output 5, 30
class(es) 32,33 # expected output 32, 33
class 16        # expected output 5
```

Here is what I have tried so far: https://regex101.com/r/eU7dF6/3

```
(class[\(es\)]*)([and|et|,|\s]*(\d{1,}))+
```

But I am able to get only the last matched digit i.e. `41` in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest grabbing all the substring with numbers after `class` or `classes`/`class(es)` and then get all the numbers from those:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\bclass(?:\(?es\)?)?(?:\s*(?:and|et|[,\s])?\s*\d+)+')
test_str = "Accepted for all the goods and services in classes 16 and 41."
results = [re.findall(r"\d+", x) for x in p.findall(test_str)]
print([x for l in results for x in l])
# => ['16', '41']
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/un5Ql0)

As `\G` construct is not supported, nor can you access the captures stack using Python `re` module, you cannot use your approach.

However, you can do it the way you did with [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

```
>>> import regex
>>> test_str = "Accepted for all the goods and services in classes 16 and 41."
>>> rx = r'\bclass(?:\(?es\)?)?(?:\s*(?:and|et|[,\s])?\s*(?P<num>\d+))+'
>>> res = []
>>> for x in regex.finditer(rx, test_str):
        res.extend(x.captures("num"))
>>> print res
['16', '41']
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, however what you have suggested is also a two fold approach just like the answer provided by `vks` and of course I could use this approach. But I would like to have a single regex that gives me the results.

Comment: but can you use a PyPi regex module? I said you can't use a single regex with `re`.

Comment: Using an external library is not a problem at all. :)

Comment: @AKS if its not a problem you can check my edit...dont using `regex` module in python

Comment: @AKS: As I mentioned, your approach (with a corrected regex) will work fine with PyPi regex module.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I used the regex module with correct regex and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 steps.Regex engine remebers only the last group in continous groups.

```
x="""Accepted for all the goods and services in classes 16 and 41."""
print re.findall(r"\d+",re.findall(r"class[\(es\)]*\s*(\d+(?:(?:and|et|,|\s)*\d+)*)",x)[0])
```

Output:`['16', '41']`

If you dont want `string` use

```
print map(ast.literal_eval,re.findall(r"\d+",re.findall(r"class[\(es\)]*\s*(\d+(?:(?:and|et|,|\s)*\d+)*)",x)[0]))
```

Output:`[16, 41]`

If you have to do it in one regex use `regex` module

```
import regex
x="""Accepted for all the goods and services in classes 16 and 41."""
print [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in regex.findall(r"class[\(es\)]*|\G(?:and|et|,|\s)*(\d+)",x,regex.VERSION1) if i]
```

Output:`[16, 41]`

Comment: Yes! I could do this in fact. but I am just wondering if there is a pure regex which could give me what I need.

Comment: @AKS check edit..you can do it using `regex` module but it is not there in default python

Comment: @vks: :) Is it bedtime there? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU7dF6/5), and you will get the idea.