# Regex multiple same pattern/repeated captures not work correctly, only match first and last

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

### My regex:

```
联系人[:：]\s{1,2}([^\s,，、]+)(?:[\s,，、]{1,2}([^\s,，、]+))*
```

### Test string:

```
联系人: 啊啊，实打实大, 好说歹说、实打实  实打实大
```

### Code

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> p = r'联系人[:：]\s*([^\s,，、]+)(?:[\s,，、]{1,2}([^\s,，、]+))*'
>>> s = '联系人: 啊啊，实打实大, 好说歹说、实打实  实打实大'
>>> re.findall(p, s)
[('啊啊', '实打实大')]

#  finditer
>>> for i in re.finditer(p, s):
...     print(i.groups())
...
('啊啊', '实打实大')
```

### Matchs:

[image]

[image]

You can test it here https://regex101.com/
(regex101 can't save regex now, so I have to post above pics)

---

I want all groups split by `[\s,，、]`, but only match the first and last. I don't feel there is any wrong in my regex, though the result is wrong, this stuck me for half hour...

Comment: It is not possible to keep repeated captures with Python `re`, you can access them with PyPi regex though.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I have tried `regex`, unfortunately same result. See my sample code.

Comment: You did not use it correctly. Use `regex.search` if you expect a single match or `regex.finditer` to get multiple matches, and then access the corresponding `group`'s `captures`. See [RegEx: Find all digits after certain string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35310519/3832970).

Comment: It looks like you are using Python 3.x, right?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Sorry, I fogot to provide the version, it is Python 3.6. And `finditer` is just more memory efficient than  `findall` , the results are same.

Comment: You did not have a look at my answer. **"and then access the corresponding group's `captures`"**

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I did... see my update.

Comment: No you did not. The values are inside the *group `captures`*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 
Sorry, I can't get your meaning, Could you give me an example ? I posted  what I tried in chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141625/discussion-between-mithril-and-wiktor-stribizew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you need to use `re.search` (to get a single match only) or `re.finditer` (to get multiple matches) and access the corresponding group `captures` (in your case, it is `captures(2)`):

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> p = r'联系人[:：]\s*([^\s,，、]+)(?:[\s,，、]{1,2}([^\s,，、]+))*'
>>> s = '联系人: 啊啊，实打实大, 好说歹说、实打实  实打实大'
>>> res = []
>>> for x in re.finditer(p, s):
    res.append(x.captures(2))

>>> print(res)
[['实打实大', '好说歹说', '实打实', '实打实大']]

>>> m = re.search(p, s)
>>> if m:
    print(m.captures(2))
['实打实大', '好说歹说', '实打实', '实打实大']
```